# Probability of winning and losing match in a group of five teams?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

We are conducting a tournament in our office. For that purpose we have made groups and each group is comprised of five teams. Each team will play four matches with each other. Now we have to pick top two teams having greater number of wins. Can you please help me how can we achieve this? Isn't there any possibility that one team has won 3 matches and other two teams have same number of wins.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this could certainly be the case.  This is why there are generally tie-breaker rules for this kind of thing.  For example, if three teams all end up with three wins, the 2nd criteria could be direct competition.  For example, if 1 beat  2 and 3 but lost to 4 and 5, 2 beat 3 and 4 but not 1 or 5, and 3 beat 4 and 5 but not 1 or 2, then the placement would be 1, 2, then 3 (i.e. 1 and 2 advance, 3 does not) since 3 lost to both in direct competition.

Comment: Now what should we do to achieve this ? Should we introduce point system or something else ? Because there 4 such groups each having 5 teams then we are thinking that two teams from each group (making total 8 teams) will qualify for the quarter final.

Comment: I would just add additional tie-breaker criteria.  For example, if 1 beat 2, 2 beat 3, and 3 beat 1, then direct competition wouldn't work.  You could use total point differential (for - against), you could use most wins in a row. ...